# drupal_goto() usage

Tags: forms

I did some research about using `drupal_goto('page')`, and I noticed that the parameters of the function can be only the path of the destination page.

I want to use this function in a form submission handler. Can I take the submitted values and use them with `drupal_goto()` as in the following code?

```
function my_module_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $database_name = $form_state['values']['databasename'];
  drupal_goto('page', $database_name);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In a form submission handler, there is no need to use `drupal_goto()`, and it should be avoided, since it stops the other form submission handlers from being called.

If you need to redirect the users to a page, you should use `$form_state['redirect']`, which accepts the same parameters used by `drupal_goto()`. In particular, the following code will redirect the users to node/123?foo=bar#baz, if other modules don't alter the redirection, and other conditions are met.

```
$form_state['redirect'] = array(
  'node/123',
  array(
    'query' => array(
      'foo' => 'bar',
    ),
    'fragment' => 'baz',
  ),
);
```

As for passing the values contained in the array `$array` to the redirection URL, that is easily done with the following code.

```
$form_state['redirect'] = array(
  // Se the values you need.
);

$form_state['redirect']['query'] = drupal_get_query_parameters($array, array());
```

If then the need is just to pass data from a page to another, there are better solutions, such as passing the data into the session data. I would rather use that, since theoretically there isn't a limit to that data stored as session data, while a URL cannot be longer than X characters.

#### Reference

- [drupal_build_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7)
- [drupal_redirect_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_redirect_form/7)
- [drupal_get_query_parameters()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_query_parameters/7)

Comment: Thenk for your answer but I still need to send an array from the first page to the second page with the use of $form_state['redirect']

Comment: Do you need the next page to have access to php data from the prior page? if so, you may need to look into `$_SESSION` variables.